# how to get to bios using term?

Tags: 12.04

I've been using Ubuntu 12.04 for a month all worked fine. I used an Ubuntu utility to clean up unnecessary files thinking it would be safe. Now my keyboard will not work. Computer is booting from hard drive so I can't boot from a disk to reinstall. I can use the onboard keyboard to type into terminal but don't know how to set the bios to boot from a cd using the command line. Any help is appreciated.I have tried to install different versions of Ubuntu but computer will only load from the hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

Changing BIOS in cmd mode is little difficult, settings can only be done in real mode, because the Command Prompt does not have access to BIOS. Unless manufacturer provides other means to exploit cmd for BIOS.

To change BIOS in manual way reboot then when booting press <kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>F8</kbd> or maybe other. serach for your manfacture key to enter bios and then change boot order as u like

Comment: Op has mentioned that the keyboard is not working so F2 or any other key wont work

Comment: He said keyboard is not working in OS not in booting...

Comment: Another key to try while powering-up the system is del